# I can't see buttons in MaterialButtonToggleGroup

Tags: android

I want to use the toggle button group to make it look like the picture below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8Ppd.png)

However, if I insert a button into the toggleButton Group, the size of the button becomes very small. Even if the absolute size is given to each layout, only the size of the toggle Button Group is enlarged and the button inside is small, so I can't see it. When you take out the button, it returns to its normal size and you can see it well, but it looks small only in the group.
Can I know the reasons about this?

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. how you ask a question here is very important, you won't find answers if you do it incorrectly. firstly, unless you're asking about android studio as an IDE, you should just use the `android` tag, not `android-studio`. secondly, you should include all the relevant code in your question for others to recreate, show what you're trying to do and what isn't working, in your case i'd probably add the xml to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that there must be separate styles in the toggleButton Group itself for buttons. Maybe you wanna check that.
Another reason I'm thinking is that maybe you have the width of the button set with % percentage, or with vh/vw(view height/width). If so button will change its size relative to the parent element size.

Comment: I had overlooked that basic them should not be used. Thank you for your answer.